# Magento SOAP Error, Bad Gateway

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a API in my magento site. I am using that API in another server machine to process the data. This was working fine in one server machine. Then again i installed xampp in new server machine and now i am getting the below error:

> SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Bad Gateway in
> C:\xampp2\htdocs\test\test.php:68  Stack trace: #0 [internal
> function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__call('call', Array)
>
> ## 2 C:\xampp2\htdocs\test\test.php(68): SoapClient->call('268e54daa25bfcb...', 'intermediate_ap...', Array)

I made changes in `php.ini` as below:

```
max_execution_time = 1800
default_socket_timeout = 120
```

But nothing is fine. Can anyone help me what should i do. I am stuck in a tight deadline and helpless.

Thank You So Much.

Answer (score 0):

Check you server logs, normally this is indicative that one thing or the other has an error, this appears to be API server side (rather than the consumer).

Bad Gateway is *"usually"* what Nginx throws back under php-fpm, so check all the logs for more information.

Your API consumer isn't correctly catching and processing the SOAP error as well.